# Problems while opening the REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, incanter

Anytime I fire up a fresh REPL I always get the same message, namely

```
#<FileNotFoundException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate test_app/core_init.class or test_app/core.cljon classpath:>
```

The namespace I've been using is `ns test-app.core`

The REPL still continues to come up and I am able to execute code with it. I am just unsure if this will lead to future problems, such as trying to work with incanter or other libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your `project.clj` contain the following line, per chance?

```
...
:main test-app.core
...
```

Leiningen will try to switch into that namespace before showing the REPL to you. If it cannot find it, you'll see the error you mentioned. Now, the reason it cannot find it is another topic to explore, so first make sure that this is how your directory structure looks like:

```
.
|-- project.clj
|-- src
    |-- test_app
        |-- core.clj
```

If it does, I guess it's time to post Leiningen and Java versions (and ideally your `project.clj`) to let SO try to tackle this miraculous REPL. :)

**Edit:** The solution to this problem would - if any of the above suggestions match your case - of course be to either remove the `:main` line from your project file or to adjust the directory structure.

Comment: I at first deleted `:main` and it took care of the error above, but then lead to a new problem in the REPL. Namely, the REPL said `user=>` and did not go into my namespace. At this point I have reinserted the `:main` line back into project, so that I can access my built functions in the namespace. @xsc

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a `core.clj` file in the folder named `test_app` in your project structure.

Basically, the file name should apply the naming towards whatever you've declared in your `ns` form.

As the [Clojure Documentation FAQ](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/FAQ) says,

> In order to use a Java class or Clojure namespace in your program,
>   that class or namespace must be "on the classpath," that is, inside a
>   directory or JAR file listed in the classpath.

Comment: Does there need to be anything inside `core.clj`? I have had such a file in the folder named `test_app`, but just saved over it with just the name space from above in the first line. My path goes from `test-app` to `src` to `test_app`.

Comment: The `ns test-app.core` statement should be inside the file `test-app/src/test_app/core.clj`